# Is there a way to make a loop take two ranges?

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to take 1 value out of 10 out of my list but I also want to take the last one (`l[19]`).

Can we do a double range in a loop?

```
l=[1]*20
for i in range(0,20,10)and range(len(l)-1,len(l)):
    print("i ="+str(i),l[i])
```

Or some other way without a double range?

```
l=[1]*20
for i in range(0,20,10):
    print("i = "+str(i), l[i])
```

Expected:  `"i = 0, 1", "i = 10, 1", "i = 19, 1"`

Actual result: `"i = 19, 1",`
Answer for python 2 : 
[How can I add non-sequential numbers to a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678410/how-can-i-add-non-sequential-numbers-to-a-range)

Best (in my humble opinion) answer for my actual python version(python 3.7) : 
(because we don't need to import a library or creat a list)

```
for i in [*range(0, len(l), 10)] + [len(l)-1]:
    print("i = {}, {}".format(str(i), l[i]))
```

Thank you all for your answers !

Comment: `range(...) and range(...)` will always evaluate to the first range, unless it's empty; `and` returns the first truthy operand. You could make a list of the indices, and add the last index if it's not there already.

Comment: Do you want `i` to iterate the first range, and then the second, or should `i` be tuples of values from the two ranges, and if so, of all combinations, or of the elements that are in the same positions?

Comment: Yeah it seems like a duplicate, i will link mine to that one or delete it if i can

Comment: link I posted (deleted) is for python 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in [*range(0, len(l), 10)] + [len(l)-1]:
    print("i = {}, {}".format(str(i), l[i]))
```

output:

```
i = 0, 1
i = 10, 1
i = 19, 1
```

or :

```
result = ["i = {}, {}".format(str(i), l[i]) for i in [*range(0, len(l), 10)] + [len(l)-1]] # ['i = 0, 1', 'i = 10, 1', 'i = 19, 1']
for item in result:
    print (item)
```

output:

```
i = 0, 1
i = 10, 1
i = 19, 1
```

I am using here *** (Extended Iterable Unpacking)** to  pass a range as a list element to a list

> *** (Extended Iterable Unpacking) operator**
>
> Proposes a change to iterable unpacking syntax, allowing to specify a
>   "catch-all" name which will be assigned a list of all items not
>   assigned to a "regular" name.
>
> ```
> rowsList = [*range(10)] 
> print (rowsList)
> ```
>
> output :
>
> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
> ```
>
> example:
>
> ```
> print ([*range(0, 50, 10)])
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```
> [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
> ```

Comment: do you know what  the "*" before the range means ?

Comment: `for i in [*range(0, len(l), 10), len(l)-1]:` is cleaner. The * unpacks the range - see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=keyword#keyword-arguments

Comment: can you explain why it is cleaner ? @AndrewAllen

Comment: *really*...erm because you are doing list concatenation when you don't need to and it looks less readable.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for x, y in zip(range(10), range(10, 0, -1)):
...     print(x, y)
...
0 10
1 9
2 8
3 7
4 6
5 5
6 4
7 3
8 2
9 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate lists with + so:

```
>>> l=[1]*20
>>> range(0, len(l), 10) + [len(l)-1]
[0, 10, 19]
```

so:

```
>>> for i in range(0, len(l), 10) + [len(l)-1]:
    print("i = "+str(i), l[i])

('i = 0', 1)
('i = 10', 1)
('i = 19', 1)
```

That gives exactly the output you are asking for, but I suspect there's some subtlety of what you *actually* want that I'm missing.

Comment: I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'list'`. Are you using python 2?

Comment: Yes, python 2.7.15. range() must return an iterator or some such rather than a list these days. You can wrap it in a list comprehension to expand it before concatenation though.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few approaches but given you probably don't want to covert to a list if you can help it given the length of list and fact you only want to append a single element I would do the following:

**Concatenate Two Ranges**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14099894/4711754

```
from itertools import chain
concatenated = chain(range(30), range(2000, 5002))
for i in concatenated:
```

So for your use case:

```
from itertools import chain
l=[1]*20

concatenated = chain(range(0, len(l), 10), [len(l)-1])
for i in concatenated:
    print("i = " + str(i), l[i])

# i = 0 1
# i = 10 1
# i = 19 1
```

Answer (score -1):

If to choose the easiest way:

```
n=19
l=[1]*(n+1)
for i in range(0,20,10):
    print("i = "+str(i)+","+ str(l[i]))
print("i = "+str(n)+","+ str(l[n]))
```